# Funciones Flecha { x : c }

Tags: javascript, funciones

Teniendo en cuenta la Destructuración mediante la lista de parámetros que soporta las funciones de Flecha en JS, ¿Qué significado tiene `{x: c}` en la siguiente función?

```
var f = ([a, b] = [1, 2], {x: c} = {x: a + b}) => a + b + c; f(); // 6
```

Especulo que es "**x** igual a **c**", o me equivoco?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esa sección sirve para renombrar la variable `x` como `c`.

En esta porción de código en específico

```
{x: c} = {x: a + b}
```

Lo que estás haciendo es dándole un valor por defecto a `x`, y ese valor resulta ser `a + b`, una vez se hace la asignación a `x` en la sección a la izquierda del igual estás renombrando la variable `x` a `c`.

Otro ejemplo para que te quede más claro sería el siguiente

```
const wes = {
  first: 'Wes',
  last: 'Bos',
  links: {
    social: {
      twitter: 'https://twitter.com/wesbos',
      facebook: 'https://facebook.com/wesbos.developer',
    },
    web: {
      blog: 'https://wesbos.com'
    }
  }
};

const { twitter: tweet, facebook: fb } = wes.links.social;
```

Con esto estás obteniendo los valores que estaban en las llaves `twitter` y `facebook`, en un principio estas llaves se llamarían de la misma forma, pero gracias a esta sintaxis puedes renombrarlos de forma diferente a su llave original, el ejemplo detallado lo puedes ver [acá](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-renaming/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var f = ([a, b] = [1, 2], {x: c} = {x: a + b}) => a + b + c; 

console.log(f()) // 6
```

Explicación:

- La función recibe 2 parámetros
- El primer parámetro es un vector de valores `a` y `b` que igualamos a otro
  vector numérico de valores `1 y 2`
- Después recibe un objeto de clave `x` con valor `c`
- La clave `x` del objeto anterior ahora tiene como valores la suma de `a y b`
- Por dentro de la función realizamos la suma de a y b que si recuerdas valen
  1 y 2 por lo que **el primer resultado parcial es 3**
- El segundo número 3 que nos dará la sumatoria de 6, lo obtenemos de:
  la clave identificada con `c` la cual está siendo igualada a la suma que está como
  valor de la clave `x` del último objeto

El último punto lo puedes comprobar retornando solo a `c` de este modo:

```js
    var f = ([a, b] = [1, 2], {x: c} = {x: a + b}) => c; 
    
    
    console.log(f()) // 3
```